# Running jobs independent of each other's failure/success in a single dataflow pipeline

Tags: pipeline, apache-beam, jobs, dataflow

I am trying to load data in Avro format from GCS to Big Query, using a single pipeline. There are 10 tables for instance that I am trying to load, which means 10 parallel jobs in a single pipeline.
Now if the 3rd job fails, all the subsequent jobs fail. How can I make the other jobs run independent of the failure/success of one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot isolate different steps within a single Dataflow pipeline without implementing custom logic (for example, custom [DoFn/ParDo](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#pardo) implementations). Some I/O connectors such as BigQuery offer a way to send failed requests to a [dead-letter queue](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/9317462f73cd3aeb42145ba41ba3b1ef0f72674b/sdks/java/io/google-cloud-platform/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/gcp/bigquery/WriteResult.java#L143) in some write modes but this might not give what you want. If you want full isolation you should run separate jobs and combine them into a workflow using a orchestration framework such as [Apache Airflow](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-google/stable/operators/cloud/dataflow.html).